# Thrift - add encoding language in python generated files

Tags: python, python-2.7, thrift

*Context*:

1. I'm developing a multi-lingual application.
2. The server-side is in python.
3. Python needs a special comment to deal with non-ASCII characters according to [pep-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).
4. I'm using Thrift (0.9.0) to generate the list of supported languages - this is due to needing the list in server-side and in client-side (JavaScript) - and the list contains the name of each language in its native language.

*Question*:

Is there a way to tell Thrift to add a comment `# coding: utf-8` in the first or second row in a python file?

Preferably, with an option to isolate it to a single file, i.e. all other files generated without the comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
thrift --gen py:coding=UTF-8 <thrift file>
```

You can check more thrift options by enter '